# Search is not working in magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, product, error, ce-1.9.2.0

When i am trying to search any product name in mobile rwd theme then i am getting the below error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home3/wowdeals/public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/rwd-ariel/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 51

Here is a piece of code:

```
<?php
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
// echo $currentCategoryId;

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addCategoryFilter($_category)
->setOrder('price', 'ASC')
->load();
?>
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because there is no current category registered on the search list.

You can change your code to the following to fix that:

```
<?php
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($_category) {
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
}

$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*');

if ($_category) {
$_productCollection->addCategoryFilter($_category);
}
$_productCollection->setOrder('price', 'ASC')
->load();
?>
```